# Puppeteer multi browser instance

Tags: express, automation, puppeteer

I want to build an express and puppeteer service that allows some users to automate their job on a web that uses authentication. I think about using one browser instance for one user. So it will open up two browser instances when there are two users. Are there any best approaches for dealing with this kind of problem?

Comment: If you open a Puppeteer instance, it will be unique per running instance, even if its on the same machine - its not sharing their "browser" between users - only if you open one instance and then on it new 'pages' (tabs) then they are shared. This means you need to take into account that each Puppeteer instance would take quite a bit of resources because of this (as its not shared)

Comment: @NoamRathaus I'm worried about my server to become lack of resources. This is just my personal project to help my college friends. So I don't want to buy any expensive resources .

Comment: Thank you @NoamRathaus